# Postgres Query WHERE array

Tags: postgresql, select, having

I have problem with my Postgres Query.

I have 3 tables:

```
1) Carrier
  *id
  *name
  *telephone
  *address
  *comments


2) Transportlist
   *id
   *name

3) Carrier_transport
   *id
   *carrier_id
   *transport_list_id
```

For Example:

```
Carrier:           Transportlist:      Carrier_transport:
ID | name          ID  |  name         ID | carrier_id  | transport_list_id
 1 | ABC            1  | Car            1 |     1                1
 2 | XYZ            2  | Tir            2 |     1                2
 3 | 111            3  | Plane          3 |     1                3
                    4  | ferry          4 |     2                1
                                        5 |     3                4
                                        6 |     3                3
                                        7 |     3                2
```

I have to select only carriers which have transportlist Car AND Tir

I tried like:

```
Select  FROM Carrier c 
LEFT JOIN Carrier_transport ct ON (ct.carrier_id = c.id)
WHERE ct.transport_list_id IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
```

But this solution is wrong.

Could somebody can help me?

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(distinct ct.transport_list_id)>=2`

Comment: But what if carrier x have one of type transport list like CAR and 10 different. It have COUNT >=2 but ONLY one element which I have to need

Comment: I don't see how the query is wrong. The combination of `carrier_id` and `transport_list_id` should be unique in `carrier_transport`. You select all records with `transport_list_id` 1 and 2 per carrier_id from the table and count if you got two records (i.e. both 1 and 2) for the carrier. What exactly does not work?

Comment: WHERE ct.transport_list_id IN (1,2)  - if I have in db carrier with transport_list_id  1 and 3 - this carrier will be selected why? Becouse this carrier have  ( transport_list_id  1 OR 2 ) And COUNT(*) >=2 problem is that transport_list_id  IS NOT 1 AND 2.

Comment: If the carrier has transport_list_id 1 and 3, then only the record with transport_list_id 1 gets selected (because 3 doesn't match `transport_list_id IN (1,2)`). One record => COUNT(*) = 1 => the carrier is not shown (`HAVING COUNT(*)>=2`). And this is exactly what you want, isn't it?

Comment: This is usually written, like `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` (or count a specific id -- it can never be greater than 2 because of your `WHERE` predicate). Also, your `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER` one because of the same `WHERE` predicate. Apart from the obvious syntax error after `SELECT`, your query is fine: it should work. What is exactly *wrong* with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
select ct.carrier_id
from
    transportlist tl 
    inner join
    carrier_transport ct on ct.transport_list_id = tl.id
where ct.transport_list_id in (1,2) 
group by 1
having bool_or(tl.id = 1) and bool_or(tl.id = 2)
```

[Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)